# NoneType error in delegate in python and WPF

Tags: python, wpf, listbox, delegates

I have some problems with WPF. My app have 2 windows: main window and dialog one, main window contains listbox. When user types data in dialog window and press button Add, some item (order) must be added in listbox. To do this I use delegate. When I press Add, NoneType error occurs in string `self.AddOrderToList(MyWindow.AddOrderToListOfOrders(MainWindow, self))`

Could anyone help me?

AddOrder.py

```
import wpf

from Course_project import MyWindow
from Ordera import Ordera
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class AddOrder(Window):

    def __init__(self):
        self.order = Ordera('','','','','','','','','','')
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'AddOrder.xaml')

    def CancelButton_Click(self, sender, e):
            self.Close()

    def AddOrderToList(self, AddToListBox):
        self.order = Ordera(self.OrderNameEdit.Text, self.CustomerNameEdit.Text, self.AddressEdit.Text, self.PhoneNumberEdit.Text, self.ContactPersonEdit.Text,\
                     self.PriceEdit.Text, self.DescriptionSelect.Text, self.ShippingSelect.Text, self.AmountEdit.Text, self.DateSelect.Text)
        AddToListBox()

    def AddButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        MainWindow = MyWindow()
        self.AddOrderToList(MyWindow.AddOrderToListOfOrders(MainWindow, self))
```

MainWindow.py

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window
from AddOrder import *

class MyWindow(Window):

    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'Main_Window.xaml')

    def AddOrderButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        AddOrderWindow = AddOrder()
        AddOrderWindow.ShowDialog()
        if AddOrderWindow.DialogResult == True:
            self.AddOrderToListOfOrders(AddOrderWindow)

    def AddOrderToListOfOrders(self, AddOrderWindow):
        self.ListOfOrders.Items.Add(AddOrderWindow.order)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```